# how to convert content in the pages and post in wordpress to word format

Tags: wordpress

How to convert content in the pages and post in wordpress to word document(docx)? Used aspose doc exporter plugin but it is "untested with your version of wordpress"! is there any solution for this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this plugin, "Aspose Importer & Exporter" plugin, it works fine.It convert content in the page and post to doc format or pdf format as per the requirement

Answer (score 0):

It works fine and I am sure it will be helpful for you 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-print/